# General questions about level sets of polynomials of two variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Sorry if I'm being too general here, but here it goes.  I'm trying to find out more about levels sets of polynomials of two variables of degree $d$

$$ C = \{ (x,y) \ :  \sum_{1 \leq i + j \leq d} c_{i,j} x^i y^j = 1 \} $$

In particular, I want a feeling of what these curves "look like" for low $d$ ($d = 3,4,5...$), and also what kind of things can be computed "exactly" (probably need special functions),  for instance:

1. When is $C$ made up of closed curve(s)?
2. When is $C$ connected?
3. What is the arc length of $C$?
4. What is the curvature of $C$?

Any tips, or paper references would be helpful too,  thanks!!

Comment: heres one result: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_curve_theorem